# Storing multiple Foreign Keys in MySQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am in a design dilemma, I am designing a database for a house rental application, the point that got me stuck is the amenities of the house, given that a house can have multi amenities like `Ceiling board,Dishwasher, Refrigerator, Paved yard, Wall fence etc` How do I store such a house in the database? Some suggestion I have been given are(Simplified tables):

```
`  |id |description|amenities|
   |1  |           |         |
```

1. Store amenity ids e.g `1,2,3,4` in the amenities column
2. Store the amenity strings in the amenities column

Between the two option 1 is best because am saving memory but isn't there a better way to store multiple ids than this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use EAV model for that, you will save memory, but will lose performance on select, or use sparse columns

**EAV approach:**

EAV table:

- entityId
- attributeId
- value

Attribute table:

- attributeId
- attribute name

Entity table:

- entityId
- entity name

Attributes would be

> Ceiling board,Dishwasher, Refrigerator, Paved yard, Wall fence etc

Entities

> house 1, house 2

**Sparse columns:**

House table:

- House id
- Your attribute(Nullable)
- Your attribute2(Nullable)
- Your attribute3(Nullable)

**Simple mapping:**

House table:

- houseId
- house name

Amenities table:

- amenityId
- name

HouseAmenitiesMapping:

- houseId
- amenityId

Comment: So if it were you what would be your way around this problem?

Comment: if you need performance and you attributes would be limited(not growing) i would use sparse columns, else attributes would grow dynamically i would use EAV with some cache to gain performance in select to select data as model you would need transpose your dataset which cost a lot

Comment: because i assume that you don't need specific value for attribute you can use just mapping table